# Releasing instances of NSNumber created with initWithInteger: vs. numberWithInt:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

On page 326 in the book *Programming in Objective-C 2.0* the author says:

```
myNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 1000];
```

> Of course, based on previous discussions, if you create `myNumber` this way, you are re- sponsible for subsequently releasing it when you’re done using it with a statement such as follows:

```
[myNumber release];
```

My question is:

Does this mean that if I create an `NSNumber` object with this statement

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 100];
```

I don't have to release the object `myNumber` myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This link is your bible](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

In the case of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` it returns an autoreleased object, and you don't need to do anything to release it properly.  Unless you `retain` it, of course, in which case you would call `release` on it, likely from your `dealloc` method.

`[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:]` returns an object with a retain count of one (from calling `alloc`).  You are responsible for releasing any object created this way.

Comment: The convention is for `alloc`, not `init`. The methods that cause you to own memory are **NARC** -- `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, `copy...`.

Comment: What about number with @, like @10 and @(id.intValue)

Answer (score 1):

Simple rules for memory management:

- When you make an object with alloc, you have the responsibility to release/autorelease it.
- When you retain an object, you have the responsibility to release/autorelease it.
- The others, it's not your responsibility, if you release/autorelease object which you don't own, crash.

Comment: It's always better to direct someone to [the rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1) than to try to restate them yourself. For example, you left out copy, new, and methods that contain those words like mutableCopy.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `alloc`, `retain`, `new`, `copy` (or `mutableCopy`), you are responsible for releasing the object.

In all other cases the object is autoreleased, and must NOT call release.

There are no compiler or run time rules that enforce this*, it's just a language naming convention, but it's used everywhere, so you can count on it to be true.

Your own code should follow this convention as well.

*Automatic Reference Counting relies on the naming convention to function properly. See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.retained_returns for details.